# Network Only Resource From Livedata To RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata

I have this class that make request call with livedata... I want to transform this class to rxjava class... Because i want to use rxjava on my repository / viewmodel classes...

Can someone help me to make this chages please?

```
abstract class NetworkOnlyResource<RequestType> {

private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<RequestType>>()

init {
    result.value = Resource.loading(null)
    fetchFromNetwork()
}

@MainThread
private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<RequestType>) {
    if (result.value != newValue) {
        result.value = newValue
    }
}

private fun fetchFromNetwork() {
    val apiResponse = createCall()
    result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
        result.removeSource(apiResponse)

        when (response) {
            is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                setValue(Resource.success(processResponse(response)))
            }

            is ApiEmptyResponse -> {
                setValue(Resource.success(null))
            }

            is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                onFetchFailed()
                setValue(Resource.error(response.errorMessage, null))
            }
        }
    }
}

protected open fun onFetchFailed() {}

fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<RequestType>>

@WorkerThread
protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<RequestType>) = response.body

@MainThread
protected abstract fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>
```

}

Comment: So in RxJava, what is it supposed to be? BehaviorRelay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer1**

If you want to "transform this class to rxjava class", something similar to this will probably do the job:

```
abstract class RxNetworkOnlyResource<RequestType> {
     private val result = BehaviorSubject.create<Resource<RequestType>>()

     init {
         createCall()
             .toObservable()
             .map { response ->
                 when (response) {
                     is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                         Resource.success(processResponse(response))
                     }

                     is ApiEmptyResponse -> {
                         Resource.success(null)
                     }

                     is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                         onFetchFailed()
                         Resource.error(response.errorMessage, null)
                     }
                 }
             }
             .startWith(Resource.loading(null))
             .subscribe(result)
     }

     protected open fun onFetchFailed() {}

     fun asObservable() = result as Observable<Resource<RequestType>>

     protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<RequestType>) = response.body         

     protected abstract fun createCall(): Single<ApiResponse<RequestType>>
}
```

`BehaviorRelay` might make more sense but `BehaviorSubject` will probably work fine in your specific case.

**Answer2**

What I recommend is to get rid of this class (vs trying to translate to RxJava). You won't need complex classes, nor all these MediatorLivedata and Transformer shenanigans with RxJava.

For example, the `LiveData` class you had can be used like this:

```
object: NetworkOnlyResource<RequestType>() {
    override fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>> {
        return someCall()
    }
}.asLiveData() // This returns LiveData<Resource<RequestType>> instance
```

Instead of having this `NetworkOnlyResource` class, you can simply do:

```
someCall().toObservable()
    .map(Utils::processResponse)
    .startWith(Resource.loading(null))
```

Comment: What means this map(Utils::processResponse)?

Comment: @Felipe A., `.map(Utils::processResponse)` this line should convert `ApiResponse` object to `Resource` object. `Utils::processResponse` is the function that you need implement which takes an `ApiResponse` instance and return a  `Resource` instance.